# Jump from wall to wall? - box2d

Tags: box2d

I was wondering how I could make a dynamic box two object move up to half the height of the wall and then stop moving up or down. Afterwards I want it to "jump" in a fixed movement to a fixed position which has to be the same y-position as it jumped from(at half the height of the wall). I really want to make my idea clear and therefore I tried to illustrate it:
https://s28.postimg.org/yheev1hx9/jumping.png

It would really mean a lot to me if you could take a look at this. Thanks!
Cheers,
Me

Answer (score 0):

There are the possible causes that `pos-Y` was modified :-

- gravity
- collision impulse
- your game logic sneakily do it (e.g. `+vy` when jump)

The possible solutions are :-

- disable gravity
- disable collision impulse (except between the dynamic box and the target wall)
- cache `Y` position, and set position OR velocity to adjust the position indirectly every frame

It depends what is the "fix jump".
Roughly speaking, if all three conditions are done, the character would have fix-Y for sure, but it would be not so realistic.

You may want to disable some conditions.

There are a lot solutions that I didn't mention, e.g. constraint, adjust acceleration, etc.   There are more than one way to do that.

Comment: Thanks and to move the dynamic box from the bottom of the wall to half the height, shouldn't i use something like constant velocity or? And you did not tell how to do the fix jump-action correct? Or am i blind.. Thanks again buddy!

Comment: fixed* jump-action*

Comment: @npp I edited the answer, I hope it will be clearer.

Comment: Thanks! I do have an idea about the fact that I probably have to turn off something but still cannot see how I am supposed to make the "player" jump to a certain point(right beside the right wall). However, a solution becomes more and more visible :)

Comment: following the path illustrated in my illustration from my post - thanks again

Comment: @npp  setVelocity = 0 when it reach?

Comment: @npp  I guess it is your first game, and this is not a hobby, right?  Asking this last very detailed question usually ruin fun of developing a game.     I recommend diving into rich tutorials in some game engine.  In my old day, Game Maker has a lot of free tutorial for its free-version software.  It greatly helps me to develop my own game/game-library.

Comment: Well, I have actually been programming for some years and have participating in making several more complex games but without box2d and do that a lot but not something like this and you are right about the previous statements about what to do in order to make the player stop move and I do know how to add impulses, forces etc. but not how to do it so that the player moves in a certain path. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I am just very good at sounding totally unlearned about something :))

Comment: Thanks anyways, I have figured it out because of your good advice :)

Comment: @npp congrat :)